# Find an arithmetic expression near to target value

Tags: c++, integer, c++17, openmp

I wrote this program as an answer to [Express a Number](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49629) challenge on the Programming Puzzles & Code Golf site; it may be worth looking there for the context.  The concept is simple (and familiar to anyone who's seen *Des Chiffres et des Lettres* or its UK version, *Countdown*): given a target number and a set of initial numbers, construct an integer expression whose value is as close as possible to the target number.

The challenge lists the following operators:

> - concatenation (1 and 2 is 12)
> - addition (1 + 2 is 3)
> - subtraction (5 - 3 = 2)
> - division (8 / 2 = 4); division is only allowed if the result is a natural number
> - multiplication (2 * 3 = 6)
> - parentheses, to override the regular precedence of operations: 2 * ( 3 + 4 ) = 14

and the following test cases:

> ```
> 14142, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
> 48077691, 6, 9, 66, 69, 666, 669, 696, 699, 966, 969, 996, 999
> 333723173, 3, 3, 3, 33, 333, 3333, 33333, 333333, 3333333, 33333333, 333333333
> 589637567, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
> 8067171096, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199
> 78649377055, 0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90, 110, 132, 156, 182, 210, 240, 272, 306, 342, 380, 420, 462, 506, 552, 600, 650, 702, 756, 812, 870, 930, 992
> 792787123866, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169
> 2423473942768, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000, 100000, 2000000, 5000000, 10000000, 20000000, 50000000
> ```

The aim is to achieve the lowest score (within a "reasonable" execution time), where the score is defined as:

> the sum of the relative errors of the expressions for the test set.
>
> For example if the target value is 125 and the returned expression
>   gives 120, the penalty score is `abs( 1 - 120/125 )` = 0.04.

---

My solution is

```c++
#include <omp.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

// We apply some principles to help us arrive at a good enough solution
// in a reasonable time:

// 1. Ruthlessly prune duplicate expressions from the candidate
//    list.  If we've seen a+b, then there's no need to consider
//    b+a.  Similarly, having seen (a+b)+c, then (a+c)+b can be
//    discounted.
// 2. Detect duplicates by storing batches of part-processed results
//    in sets before sending to the next pass.
// 3. Sort our candidates so that those containing a term near to the
//    target are first in line for further processing.
// 4. Gradually widen our acceptance margin as we proceed.  This
//    allows us to terminate quickly without exhaustively searching
//    the full problem space.
// 5. Parallelize the generation of candidate solutions using OpenMP.

//#define CONCAT_DIGITS

// Define precedence values for our operators, so that we can print
// with the minimum sufficient parentheses.  The values are grouped
// into tens so that add/10 == subtract/10 and mult/10 == divide/10 -
// the operators use that for avoiding duplicate expressions.
static const int PREC_ADD = 26;
static const int PREC_SUBTRACT = 24;
static const int PREC_MULT = 16;
static const int PREC_DIVIDE = 14;
static const int PREC_CONCAT = 2;
static const int PREC_LITERAL = 0;

static const int PREC_MAX = 1000;

class LiteralTerm;

struct Term
{
    long value;
    int precedence;

    Term(long value, int precedence)
        : value(value), precedence(precedence)
    {}
    Term(const Term&) = default;
    virtual ~Term() = default;

    virtual std::string to_string(int p = PREC_MAX) const = 0;
    virtual LiteralTerm as_literal() const = 0;

    long distance(long target) const { return std::abs(value - target); }

    // We sort large values first, in the hope that this will approach
    // the target faster.
    bool operator<(const Term& o) const { return value > o.value; }
};


// We have two kinds of Term: a LiteralTerm is a leaf node of the
// expression tree, and a BinaryTerm is an internal node.
struct Operator;

class LiteralTerm : public Term
{
    std::string s;
public:
    LiteralTerm(std::string s) : Term(std::stol(s), 0), s(s) {}
    LiteralTerm(std::string s, long value) : Term(value, 0), s(s) {}
    std::string to_string(int = PREC_MAX) const override { return s; }
    LiteralTerm as_literal() const override { return *this; }
};

struct BinaryTerm : public Term
{
    Operator const *op;

    std::shared_ptr<const Term> a;
    std::shared_ptr<const Term> b;

    BinaryTerm(long value, const Operator* op, std::shared_ptr<const Term> a, std::shared_ptr<const Term> b);
    BinaryTerm(const BinaryTerm&) = default;
    BinaryTerm& operator=(const BinaryTerm&) = default;

    std::string to_string(int p = PREC_MAX) const;

    LiteralTerm as_literal() const override { return { to_string(), value }; }
};

struct TermList {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Term>> terms;
    std::vector<long> values;
    long target_value;
    long badness;

    TermList(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Term>> terms, long target_value)
        : terms(std::move(terms)),
          values(),
          target_value(target_value),
          badness(min_badness(this->terms, target_value))
    {
        values.reserve(terms.size());
        std::transform(terms.begin(), terms.end(),
                       std::back_inserter(values), [](auto t) { return t->value; });
        // Literals that begin with "0" need to be distinct from (but
        // adjacent to) equivalent non-literals.  Append a negative
        // value for each term with leading zeros.  There's an edge
        // case involving multiple leading zeros, but we'll ignore
        // that.
        for (const auto& v: terms)
            if (v->precedence <= PREC_CONCAT && v->value > 0 && v->to_string()[0] == '0')
                values.push_back(-v->value);
    }

    // Sort according to the term that's nearest to the target.
    bool operator<(const TermList& o) const
    {
        return std::make_tuple(std::cref(badness),   std::cref(values))
            <  std::make_tuple(std::cref(o.badness), std::cref(o.values));
    }

private:
    static long min_badness(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Term>>& t, long target_value)
    {
        auto less_bad = [target_value](const auto& a, const auto&b)
            { return a->distance(target_value) < b->distance(target_value); };
        auto const& e = *std::min_element(t.begin(), t.end(), less_bad);
        return std::abs(e->value - target_value);
    }
};

using Set = std::set<TermList>;

// Detect duplicate expressions.  This will discount "3+2-3", "8*5*2/3/5"
// and similar expressions that contain simple pairs of inverse operands.
static bool contains_value(const Term& t, int precedence, long value)
{
    auto *const b = dynamic_cast<const BinaryTerm*>(&t);
    if (t.precedence == precedence)
        return t.value == value
            || b && b->b->value < value
            || b && contains_value(*b->a, precedence, value)
            || b && contains_value(*b->b, precedence, value);
    if (t.precedence/10 == precedence/10)
        // Advance through the subtractions to inspect the additons
        // (or through the divides to inspect the multiplications).
        return b && contains_value(*b->a, precedence, value);
    return false;
}

// An Operator is a factory producing binary terms of a given type,
// and for printing those terms.  Here's the abstract base class.
struct Operator
{
    using TermPointer = std::shared_ptr<const Term>;
    using BinaryTermPointer = std::shared_ptr<const BinaryTerm>;

    int const precedence;
    std::string const joiner;

    virtual std::string to_string(const Term &a, const Term &b) const {
        return a.to_string(precedence) + joiner + b.to_string(precedence);
    }

    virtual BinaryTermPointer make_term(TermPointer a, TermPointer b) const {
        long r = evaluate(*a, *b);
        return r ? std::make_shared<BinaryTerm>(r, this, a, b) : BinaryTermPointer();
    }

    virtual ~Operator() = default;

protected:
    Operator(int precedence, std::string joiner) : precedence(precedence), joiner(joiner) {}

    virtual long evaluate(const Term& a, const Term& b) const = 0;
};

// Now we define a subclass for each permitted operator
struct AddOperator : Operator
{
    AddOperator() : Operator(PREC_ADD, "+") {}

    long evaluate(const Term& a, const Term& b) const override
    {
        const auto *d = dynamic_cast<const BinaryTerm*>(&a);
        long r;
        return b.precedence/10 != PREC_ADD/10
            && a.precedence != PREC_SUBTRACT
            && b.value > 0
            && ! (d && d->precedence == this->precedence && d->b->value < b.value)
            && !__builtin_add_overflow(a.value, b.value, &r)
            ? r : 0;
    }
};
struct SubtractOperator : Operator
{
    SubtractOperator() : Operator(PREC_SUBTRACT, "-") {}

    long evaluate(const Term& a, const Term& b) const override
    {
        return b.precedence < PREC_SUBTRACT
            && a.value > b.value
            && !contains_value(a, PREC_ADD, b.value)
            ? a.value - b.value : 0;
    }
};
struct MultiplyOperator : Operator
{
    MultiplyOperator() : Operator(PREC_MULT, "*") {}

    long evaluate(const Term& a, const Term& b) const override
    {
        const auto *d = dynamic_cast<const BinaryTerm*>(&a);
        long r;
        return b.precedence/10 != PREC_MULT/10
            && b.value > 1
            && (b.value > 2 || a.value > 2)
            && ! (d && d->precedence == this->precedence && d->b->value < b.value)
            && !__builtin_mul_overflow(a.value, b.value, &r)
            ? r : 0;
    }
};
struct DivideOperator : Operator
{
    DivideOperator() : Operator(PREC_DIVIDE, "/") {}

    long evaluate(const Term& a, const Term& b) const override
    {
        return b.precedence/10 != PREC_DIVIDE/10 && b.value > 1
            && a.value % b.value == 0
            && !contains_value(a, PREC_MULT, b.value)
            ? a.value / b.value : 0;
    }
};

struct ConcatOperator : Operator
{
    ConcatOperator() : Operator(PREC_CONCAT, "") {}

    long evaluate(const Term& a, const Term& b) const override
    {
#ifdef CONCAT_DIGITS
        if (a.precedence > PREC_CONCAT || a.value == 0 || b.precedence >= PREC_CONCAT)
            return 0;
#else  // CONCAT_FULL
        if (b.precedence == PREC_CONCAT || a.value == 0)
            return 0;
#endif
        long bv = b.value, av = a.value, x = 1, r;
        if (b.precedence > PREC_CONCAT) while (x <= bv) x*= 10;
        else { int d = b.to_string().length(); while (d--) x*= 10; }
        return __builtin_mul_overflow(av, x, &r) || __builtin_add_overflow(r, bv, &r) ? 0 : r;
    }
};
struct ReverseConcatOperator : ConcatOperator
{
    BinaryTermPointer make_term(TermPointer a, TermPointer b) const override
    {
        return ConcatOperator::make_term(b, a);
    }
};

static const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Operator>> ops{
#ifndef CONCAT_NONE
        std::make_shared<ConcatOperator>(),
        std::make_shared<ReverseConcatOperator>(),
#endif
        std::make_shared<MultiplyOperator>(),
        std::make_shared<AddOperator>(),
        std::make_shared<SubtractOperator>(),
        std::make_shared<DivideOperator>(),
};


// Implement the BinaryTerm members that use Operator
BinaryTerm::BinaryTerm(long value, const Operator* op, std::shared_ptr<const Term> a, std::shared_ptr<const Term> b)
    : Term(value, op->precedence), op(op), a(std::move(a)), b(std::move(b))
{}

std::string BinaryTerm::to_string(int p) const
{
    auto const s = op->to_string(*a, *b);
    return (p/10) < (precedence/10) ? "("+s+")" : s;
}


// An object to represent our target value, and how close we have
// reached so far.
struct Target
{
    const long value;
    double max_badness = 0;

    LiteralTerm best = {"0"};
    long best_badness = value;

    bool done() const { return best_badness < max_badness; }
    double score() const { return 1.*best_badness/value; }

    void update(const Term& t)
    {
        auto badness = std::abs(t.value - value);
        if (badness < best_badness) {
            best = t.as_literal();
            best_badness = badness;
        }
    }

    void update(const TermList& terms)
    {
        for (auto t: terms.terms)
            update(*t);
    }

    void increase_threshold(size_t items_seen)
    {
        // Adjust our acceptance threshold nearer to accepting 0 by
        // 0.01% for every million values seen.
        max_badness += (value - max_badness) * .0001 * std::exp(items_seen / 1000000);
    }
};

// OpenMP reduction for sets
auto merge(auto& a, auto& b)
{
    auto it = a.begin();
    for (auto&& e: b)
        it = a.insert(std::move(e)).first;
    return a;
}
#pragma omp declare reduction(merge: Set: merge<Set>(omp_out, omp_in) ) \
    initializer(omp_priv = Set())


// We run a cascade of pair-wise combination steps, where for each
// input TermList, we generate every possible allowed pairing of its
// terms, and pass that through (in batches) to the next stage.
struct Combiner
{
    std::unique_ptr<Combiner> const next;
    Target& target;
    size_t const max_output_size;
    size_t const nterms;

    Set input = {};
    size_t output_size = 0;

    Combiner(Target& target, size_t nterms, size_t max_output_size)
        : next(nterms > 0 ? std::make_unique<Combiner>(target, nterms-1, max_output_size) : nullptr),
          target(target),
          max_output_size(max_output_size),
          nterms(nterms)
    {}

    inline void insert(const TermList&& t)
    {
        target.update(t);
        if (target.done()) return;
        if (next) {
            if (input.insert(t).second)
                output_size += count_distinct_pairs(t);
            if (output_size >= max_output_size)
                process_input();
        }
    }

    void finish()
    {
        process_input();
        if (next)
            next->finish();
    }

private:
    // Here's where we do the real work - generating and sifting the
    // combined terms for the next pass.
    void process_input()
    {
        if (target.done()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!next)
            return;

        // Move the elements into a vector, so we can parallelize the
        // for-loop.
        auto in = std::vector<Set::value_type>();
        in.reserve(input.size());
        std::move(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(in));
        input.clear();
        output_size = 0;

        auto out = Set();

#pragma omp parallel reduction(merge:out)
        {
#pragma omp for
            for (auto it = in.begin();  it < in.end();  ++it)
            {
                try {
                    const auto end = it->terms.cend();
                    for (auto i = it->terms.cbegin();  i != end;  i = std::upper_bound(i, end, *i))
                        for (auto j = i+1;  j != end;  j = std::upper_bound(j, end, *j)) {
                            for (const auto& op: ops) {
                                auto x = op->make_term(*i, *j);
                                if (x) out.insert(replace(*it, i, j, x));
                            }
                        }
                } catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
                    // Ignore it; process what we've generated so far.
                }
            }
        }

        // Now we're in single-threaded code, we can pass the combined
        // results to the next combiner.
        for (auto& o: out)
            next->insert(std::move(o));

        target.increase_threshold(out.size());
    }


    // Helper methods used by the above

    // An upper bound on the possible number of output TermLists,
    // assuming every combination is valid.  If all n terms in the
    // input list are distinct, that's just ½n(n-1), but if values
    // are duplicated, we need to reduce n to the number of distinct
    // values, and then add in the cases where we pick two of the
    // same value.
    static int count_distinct_pairs(const TermList& terms)
    {
        int distinct = 0, duplicated = 0;
        auto it = terms.terms.begin(),
            end = terms.terms.end();
        while (it != end) {
            ++distinct;
            auto const& v = (*it)->value;
            if (++it == end || (*it)->value != v) continue;
            ++duplicated;
            while (++it != end && (*it)->value == v)
                ;
        }
        return distinct * (distinct - 1) / 2 + duplicated;
    }

    // Create a new TermList from o by replacing elements i and j with
    // newly-created term n.
    static TermList replace(const TermList& o, auto i, auto j, std::shared_ptr<const Term> n)
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Term>> r;
        r.reserve(o.terms.size() - 1);
        auto added = false;
        for (auto k = o.terms.begin();  k != o.terms.end();  ++k) {
            if (!added && (*k)->value < n->value) { r.push_back(n); added = true; }
            if (k != i && k != j) r.push_back(*k);
        }
        if (!added) r.push_back(n);
        return { r, o.target_value };
    }
};


#include <iostream>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Term& t)
{
    return o << t.to_string()<< " = " << t.value;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const TermList& t)
{
    auto *sep = "";
    o << "[" << t.badness << "] ";
    for (auto const& x: t.terms)
        o << sep << *x, sep = ", ";
    return o;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " target term ...";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto target = Target{std::stol(*++argv)};

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Term>> terms;
    while (*++argv) {
        auto t = std::make_shared<LiteralTerm>(*argv);
        target.update(*t);
        terms.push_back(t);
    }
    std::sort(terms.begin(), terms.end());

    // Construct the sieve
    Combiner search{target, terms.size(), 2500000/terms.size() + 1}; // tunable - max set size
    search.insert({terms, target.value});
    search.finish();

    std::cout << "score " << std::fixed << target.score() << " for " << target.best << std::endl;
}
```

I compiled this using GCC 6.2, using `g++ -std=c++17 -fopenmp -march=native -O3` (along with some debugging and warning options).

Since concatenation is not a feature of the original versions of the challenge, I've provided a compile-time feature toggle to make it optional: define `CONCAT_NONE` for traditional Countdown rules that don't permit concatenation, or `CONCAT_DIGITS` to allow concatenation of the input values, but not of any intermediate results.  By default, without either defined, the most liberal rules are used.

I've intentionally omitted any input validation in `main()` - for a general user-facing program, I would add that, along with usage guidance.  For now, it's just sufficient to be driven by the shell script which calculates the score value from all the runs:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

program=./49629

ulimit -S -v 14680064              # 14GB, for a 16GB machine

xjobs -v 2 -j 2 $program <<EOF \
    | tee /dev/tty \
    | grep -oP 'score \K[^ ]+' | sed -z 's/\n/+/g;s/+$/\n/' \
    | bc | sed 's/^/total score = /'
2423473942768 1 2 5 10 20 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 10000 20000 50000 100000 2000000 5000000 10000000 20000000 50000000
792787123866 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17711 28657 46368 75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040 1346269 2178309 3524578 5702887 9227465 14930352 24157817 39088169
78649377055 0 2 6 12 20 30 42 56 72 90 110 132 156 182 210 240 272 306 342 380 420 462 506 552 600 650 702 756 812 870 930 992
8067171096 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181 191 193 197 199
589637567 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
333723173 3 3 3 33 333 3333 33333 333333 3333333 33333333 333333333
48077691 6 9 66 69 666 669 696 699 966 969 996 999
14142 10 11 12 13 14 15
EOF

exit 0
```